# Ksoap2 Android adding Attributes to a simple property

Tags: android, properties, attributes, ksoap2

I am trying to create a new property inside a SoapObject that will contain simple string properties with attributes to them like this:

```
<Power Unit="kw">1500</Power>
```

here is the code i am using for my samples below.

```
final SoapObject powerObject= new SoapObject(namespace, "Power");
        powerObject.addAttribute("Unit", getPowerUnit());

        PropertyInfo powerObjectProperty = new PropertyInfo();
        powerObjectProperty .setName("");
        powerObjectProperty .type = String.class;
        powerObjectProperty .setValue(getPower());
        powerObjectProperty .addProperty(powerObjectProperty);
        root.addSoapObject(powerObject); // this is my root for the hierarchy
```

The best that i could reach is the following:

```
<Power Unit="kw"><>1500</></Power>
```

i even tried to add everything as a string but that encodes the <> tags.

```
&ltPower Unit"kw"&gt1500&lt/Power&gt
```

I am using:

ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar on android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i have solved this issue, here is how:

I have created a new soap object called TextSoapObject

```
public class TextSoapObject extends SoapObject {
    public static final String TAG = TextSoapObject.class.getSimpleName();

    public TextSoapObject(String namespace, String name) {
        super(namespace, name);
    }

    public String text;

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Next i overrided SoapSerialization envelope like this:

```
public class ValueSerializationEnvelope extends SoapSerializationEnvelope {

    public ValueSerializationEnvelope(int version) {
        super(version);
    }

    public static final String TAG = ValueSerializationEnvelope.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public void writeObjectBody(XmlSerializer writer, KvmSerializable obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj instanceof TextSoapObject) {
            writer.text(((TextSoapObject) obj).getText());
        }
        super.writeObjectBody(writer, obj);
    }
}
```

And that's it.

To use this you would do the following:

```
final TextSoapObject costOfRepairs = new TextSoapObject(namespace, "CostOfRepairs");
        costOfRepairs.addAttribute("Currency", getCurrency());
        costOfRepairs.setText(getRepairCosts() + "");
        root.addSoapObject(costOfRepairs);
```

**EDIT:**

This issue has been recognized for the ksoap2 library and addressed here:

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=112

Should be fixed in the next ksoap2 Release.

Comment: So now that this is fixed, how would you addAttribute with the current ksoap2 release using your code sample?  Could you add another edit?

Comment: Figured it out for my case, you might want to check it out if you don't have text between the start and end tags..important work Donnie..

Comment: You can dowload the updated version of the library here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android/3.6.2/

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
SoapObject soOriginDestInfo = new SoapObject(namespace_ns, "OriginDestinationInformation");
SoapPrimitive spDeptDtTm = new SoapPrimitive(namespace_ns, "DepartureDateTime", "asdadsad");
spDeptDtTm.addAttribute("Unit", "kw");
soOriginDestInfo.addProperty("DepartureDateTime", spDeptDtTm);
request.addSoapObject(soOriginDestInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add property in your soap object and pass any value you want.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, NAME);
request.addProperty("powerInKw", 1500);
```

like a key value pair.

Comment: if i do that i cannot add attributes to that property. i want to be able to add the unit to in your case powerInKw.
what you have written outputs to <powerInKw>1500</powerInKw>

Answer (score 0):

I'm consuming some .NET web services and need to addAttribute to an addProperty while using ksoap for this xml:

```
    <Element FirstAttribute="int" SecondAttribute="double" />
```

Here's what I did (including some extra help looping and passing in a double) to pass in this request:

```
    String xml = null;
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://yournamespace.org/";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://yournamespace.org/NameOfYourOperation";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "NameOfYourOperation";
    final String URL = "http://whereyourserviceis.com/Service.asmx";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    for (int i=0; i < anArray.size(); i++)
    {
        Some_obj obj = anArray.get(i);
        SoapObject attributes = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Element");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(obj.someIntString);
        attributes.addAttribute("FirstAttribute", a);
        Double v = Double.parseDouble(obj.someDoubleString);
        attributes.addAttribute("Value", v);
        request.addProperty("SecondAttribute", attributes);
        //request.addSoapObject(request);
        Log.d(TAG,"=======obj.someIntString======: " + a + "=======obj.someDoubleString========: " + v);
    }
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    MarshalFloat md = new MarshalFloat();
    md.register(envelope);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);

    try
    {
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
        transport.debug = true;
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        xml = transport.responseDump.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "getUpdates===============" + xml);
    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
        Log.e("SocketException : " , "Error on getUpdates() " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception : " , "Error on getUpdates() " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Take note of the MarshalFloat part...this is there if you're passing in a double value so the soap can serialize properly.